# Azure SQL Edge container failed to start on M1, when mapping volume to relative path

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, azure-sql-edge

On an M1 Macbook, I followed online examples and successfully start Azure SQL Edge container with basic configuration.
Then I want to map a volume (mySpecialFolder) by "Path to the host, relative to the Compose file".
Here we want "./mySpecialFolder:/tmp", not "mySpecialFolder:/tmp".

```
services:
  mssql:
    container_name: mssql
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:latest"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "something"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    expose:
      - 1433
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    networks:
      - sql
    volumes:
      - ./mySpecialFolder:/tmp
      - mssqlsystem:/var/opt/mssql
```

It failed to load and reports

```
Azure SQL Edge will run as non-root by default.
This container is running as user mssql.
To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2140520.
2022/07/29 11:00:39 [launchpadd] INFO: Extensibility Log Header: <timestamp> <process> <sandboxId> <sessionId> <message>
2022/07/29 11:00:39 [launchpadd] WARNING: Failed to load /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf ini file with error open /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf: no such file or directory
2022/07/29 11:00:39 [launchpadd] INFO: DataDirectories =  /bin:/etc:/lib:/lib32:/lib64:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/include:/usr/lib:/usr/lib32:/usr/lib64:/usr/libexec/gcc:/usr/sbin:/usr/share:/var/lib:/opt/microsoft:/opt/mssql-extensibility:/opt/mssql/mlservices:/opt/mssql/lib/zulu-jre-11:/opt/mssql-tools
2022/07/29 11:00:39 Drop permitted effective capabilities.
2022/07/29 11:00:39 [launchpadd] INFO: Polybase remote hadoop bridge disabled
2022/07/29 11:00:39 [launchpadd] INFO: Launchpadd is connecting to mssql on localhost:1431
2022/07/29 11:00:39 [launchpadd] WARNING: Failed to connect to SQL because: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1431: connect: connection refused, will reattempt connection.
This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Fri Jul 29 11:00:40 2022
The following diagnostic information is available:

         Reason: 0x00000007
         Status: 0xc0000002
        Message: Failed to load KM driver [Npfs]
    Stack Trace:
                 file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000030E879
                 file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000030DB54
                 file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000030AB96
                 file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000030961D
                 file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000034EE01
          Stack:
                 IP               Function
                 ---------------- --------------------------------------
                 0000aaaac9c2ba70 std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~_Sp_counted_base()+0x25d0
                 0000aaaac9c2b618 std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~_Sp_counted_base()+0x2178
                 0000aaaac9c39d74 std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~_Sp_counted_base()+0x108d4
                 0000aaaac9c3a75c std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~_Sp_counted_base()+0x112bc
                 0000aaaac9ced6c4 std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_
                 0000ffffb9e44df8 S_SbtUnimplementedInstruction+0x2542b4
                 0000ffffb9e4472c S_SbtUnimplementedInstruction+0x253be8
                 0000ffffb9e45238 S_SbtUnimplementedInstruction+0x2546f4
                 0000ffffb9e3ca90 S_SbtUnimplementedInstruction+0x24bf4c
                 0000ffffb9e395dc S_SbtUnimplementedInstruction+0x248a98
                 0000ffffb9ed8ddc S_SbtUnimplementedInstruction+0x2e8298
                 0000ffffb9e38e44 S_SbtUnimplementedInstruction+0x248300
                 0000ffffb9e38b98 S_SbtUnimplementedInstruction+0x248054
                 0000ffffb9e38604 S_SbtUnimplementedInstruction+0x247ac0
                 0000ffffb9e38ffc S_SbtUnimplementedInstruction+0x2484b8
                 0000ffffbdb248a4 CallGuestFunction+0x84
                 0000ffffbdb1f964 Sbt::Dispatcher::SimulateCpu(Sbt::GuestCtx*)+0x2c
                 0000ffffbdb20d9c Sbt::RuntimeImpl::SimulateCpu(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x3c8
                 0000ffffbdb219e4 Sbt::SimulateCpu(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x30
                 0000ffffbdb22c04 SbtRtSimulateCpu+0x84
                 0000aaaac9c42164 std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~_Sp_counted_base()+0x18cc4
                 0000aaaac9c3fe34 std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~_Sp_counted_base()+0x16994
        Process: 24 - sqlservr
         Thread: 28 (application thread 0x4)
    Instance Id: 76bd6c34-28e2-4a7f-9e5a-f3ffa17d9c1a
       Crash Id: a022551e-96fe-4a59-ada3-4da01d244653
    Build stamp: 06cd67626d2ebedd8721dc1bd892cdda65157cdcd6ac004bb81acdd6498ec618
   Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS aarch64
     Processors: 5
   Total Memory: 8232747008 bytes
      Timestamp: Fri Jul 29 11:00:40 2022
     Last errno: 2
Last errno text: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Aside... `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "something"` is the environment variable you're looking for. Ref: [Azure SQL Edge - dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-sql-edge) You'll need to delete and recreate the container for the change to take effect though, because the password only gets set on initial creation.

Comment: The first errors seem more related to `mssqlsystem`. Does the `mssqlsystem` volume already exist _before_ you try to start the container? The dockerbackend process does not create these on the fly for you. If it's meant to be a host path instead of a volume then prepend it with `./` and, likewise, create it before starting the container.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thx for the reply, this is from the original working docker file from intel platform, the only thing changed is the image which is pointing to sql edge now.

Comment: One assumes that you're trying to use `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge` because `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` isn't compatible with M1/M2 Macs. They are different images and have different requirements, including the difference in the `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` and `SA_PASSWORD` environment variables. If you were to `docker run -it --rm "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:latest" ls -la /tmp` you'll notice there's a `dotnet-install.sh` script there which becomes hidden when your volume sets up a `/tmp` mount point. Not saying that's the cause, but it might be contributing.